# Getting error from a Terraform file that's supposed to create an AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have a Terraform file that's supposed to create an AWS VPC remotely, but every time I run `terraform apply` I get the following errors:

```
│ Error: error waiting for EC2 NAT Gateway (nat-0ddd4f893ecbaa66b) create: unexpected state 'failed', wanted target 'available'. last error: Resource.AlreadyAssociated: Elastic IP address [eipalloc-0d420da39dea25c38] is already associated
│
│   with aws_nat_gateway.NATgw[2],
│   on main.tf line 91, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw":
│   91: resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: error waiting for EC2 NAT Gateway (nat-0ea71e57475b449ec) create: unexpected
state 'failed', wanted target 'available'. last error: Resource.AlreadyAssociated:
Elastic IP address [eipalloc-0d420da39dea25c38] is already associated
│
│   with aws_nat_gateway.NATgw[0],
│   on main.tf line 91, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw":
│   91: resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
│
```

And this is the `main.tf` I'm trying to run:

```
terraform {

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "~> 3.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
   }

}

//Creating VPC here
resource "aws_vpc" "Main" {       
  provider         = aws.east
  cidr_block       = "IP_Address"
  instance_tenancy = "default"
}

//Creating Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "IGW" {
  provider = aws.east
  vpc_id =  aws_vpc.Main.id
}

//Creating Public Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "publicsubnets" {
  provider   = aws.east
  count      = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc_id     =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  cidr_block = "${var.public_subnets[count.index]}" //CIDR block of public subnets
}

//Creating Private Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "privatesubnets" {
  provider   = aws.east
  count      = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  vpc_id     =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  cidr_block = "${var.private_subnets[count.index]}" //CIDR block of private subnets
}

//Creating Route Table for Public Subnets
resource "aws_route_table" "PublicRT" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc_id   =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "IP_Address" //Traffic from Public Subnet reaches Internet via Internet Gateway
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.IGW.id
  }
}

//Creating Route Table for Private Subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "PrivateRT" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.Main.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "IP_Address" //Traffic from Private Subnet reaches Internet via NAT Gateway
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.NATgw[count.index].id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "PublicRTassociation" {
  provider       = aws.east
  count          = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.publicsubnets[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.PublicRT[count.index].id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "PrivateRTassociation" {
  provider       = aws.east
  count          = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.privatesubnets[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.PrivateRT[count.index].id
}

resource "aws_eip" "nateIP" {
  provider = aws.east
  vpc      = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
  provider      = aws.east
  count         = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nateIP.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.privatesubnets[count.index].id
}
```

I have the provider and variables for main provided in separate files. Also, I'm trying to create multiple public and private subnets with multiple IP Address blocks, which is the reason for the count variables and arguments.

Note: I've changed some names and variables for privacy/security.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Limbo, I have exactly same issue. I'm trying to understand your code but I don't understand how you variable "private_subnets" are set. Is it a number variable for the count ? But, what is the "count.index" for the cider_block ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you create **only one EIP**, and try to use it in multiple NAT gateways. You have to create 1 EIP for each NAT. Thus it should be:

```
resource "aws_eip" "nateIP" {
  provider      = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc      = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
  provider      = aws.east
  count         = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nateIP[count.index].id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.privatesubnets[count.index].id
}
```